# Params Passed not Saving from Sortable Nested Form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

So I'm using jquerys sortable to sort nested form fields. Here's controller method it's submitting to when it's sorted:

```
def sort_questions
  params[:questions_attributes].to_a.each_with_index do |id, index|
    question = Question.find(id)
    question.position = index + 1
    question.save(:validate => false)
  end
  render :nothing => true
end
```

Here's the params that get passed by looking at my inspector in Chrome:

```
 "questions_attributes"=>{"1"=>{"content"=>"Where did you grow up?", "position"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"2"}, "0"=>{"content"=>"What are you doing?", "position"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"3"}}
```

Here's the the jquery sortable function that's being called:

```
  $('#questions').sortable({
    items:'.fields',
    placeholdet: true,
    axis:'y',
    update: function() {
      $.post("/templates/#{@template.id}/sort_questions?_method=post&" + $('.edit_template').serialize());
    }
  });
```

The position attribute is not saving. I've tried all kinds of variations of the sort_questions method over and over again with no luck.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Here's the full params:

```
"template"=>{"name"=>"Long Term Volunteer Opportunity", "description"=>"This template will be for opportunities that are for long term missionaries.", "default"=>"1", "questions_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"content"=>"What are you doing?", "position"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"3"}, "1"=>{"content"=>"Where did you grow up?", "position"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"2"}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might have to wittle at this a little, I see a couple potential problems:

```
def sort_questions
  params[:questions_attributes].to_a.each_with_index do |id, index|
    question = Question.find(id)
    question.position = index + 1
    question.save(:validate => false)
  end
  render :nothing => true
end
```

As mentioned by @nodrog, it should be `params[:template][:questions_attributes]` . Currently `params[:questions_attributes]` returns `nil`, and `nil.to_a` is `[]`, so that loop never executes. Once it does, `id` in the loop will be something like:

```
[["0",{"content"=>"What are you doing?",...}], ... ]
```

Passing that to `find` won't work. You could use a lesser-known syntax like:

```
params[:template][:questions_attributes].to_a.each_with_index do |(id, attrs), index|
  question = Question.find(id)
  question.position = index + 1
  question.save(:validate => false)
end
```

Next, hashes in 1.9 *are* sorted, but I wouldn't count on the round-trip from form elements to the params hash, including decoding, to be sorted the same way you have on your page (thus allowing the `each_with_index` strategy). You need to use the `"position"` attribute from the query params, which is currently blank. I'm sure there are a million ways to sort and populate that field, google will probably have lots of info on how to do that.

So, your final function should look something like:

```
params[:template][:questions_attributes].to_a.each_with_index do |(id, attrs), index|
  question = Question.find(id)
  question.position = attrs['position']
  question.save # the less validations you skip the better in the long run.
end
```

Comment: See the change that I added at the end of your post. Now it works properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 params[:template][:questions_attributes]
```

Comment: Already tried that... no dice.But that's why I have ```question.save(:validate => false)``` so it would skip validation.

Comment: It's definitely ```params[:questions_attributes]``` but i'll add the full params so you can see just now. It's because it's sorting nested form fields that it's ```params[:questions_attributes]``` and not ```params[:questions]```.

Comment: try params[:template][:questions_attributes], if you put a debugger in there are params[:questions_attributes] nil? Sorry i missed the part about being nested! I have edited my answer...